# Why is this for-loop giving me a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, for-loop, nullpointerexception

This code is giving me a `NullPointerException`. Its purpose is to loop through an `ArrayList` and return any Records that match the parameter, age.

```
private String searchAge(int age) {

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {    //<--- ERROR ON THIS LINE
        if(list.get(i).getAge() == age) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            return list.get(i).toString();
        }
    }

    return "No Records Found!";
}
```

My Constructor:

```
public Frame() {
    Objects a = new Objects();
    list = a.getList();
}
```

And The Other Class:

```
package objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Objects {


    public ArrayList<Student> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Objects a = new Objects();
        a.addStudents();
        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void addStudents() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Student("Joe Wilson", 16, 11));
        list.add(new Student("Bill Johnson", 16, 10));
        list.add(new Student("Joe Jonson", 15, 9));
        list.add(new Student("William Smith", 17, 12));
        list.add(new Student("Dan Smith", 16, 11));

    }

}
```

Comment: Well list is `null`. You have to check why now.

Comment: Where is `list` initialized and populated?

Comment: Sorry I'll Add That part.

Comment: So `list` is `null`, it hasn't been initialised at this point.  A debugger would show you what you need to know BTW.

Comment: But if I print list in my constructor, it does print everything.

Comment: When is `searchAge` called in relation to `addStudents`? The problem I see is a design issue; you're only ever constructing the `list` object in the `addStudents()` method; it would probably make more sense to do so in the `Objects` class's constructor. That way your object is never in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your Frame constructor :

```
public Frame() {
    Objects a = new Objects(); //<-- new object of type Objects
    list = a.getList(); //<-- call getList but list is null
}
```

Two solutions are possible :

---

Keep your current constructor :

```
public Frame() {
        Objects a = new Objects(); 
        a.addStudents(); // <-- calling this method will initialize your list
        list = a.getList();
}
```

---

Consider pass the `Objects` object (btw you should use another name) as argument :

```
public Frame(Objects a) {
    list = a.getList(); //<-- call getList but list is null
}
```

And then in your main :

```
Frame f = new Frame(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < (list != null) ? list.size() : 0; i++) {
```

Or, if you do not like the ternary operator (it is rather ugly). Add these lines before your for loop

```
if (list == null || list.size() < 1) {
  return "No Records Found!";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much this helps the OP. Yes it solves the problem, but I'd rather not have this kind of code in my for loops.

Comment: I agree with Will. This is messy code, _and_ most likely hides the problem rather than solving it.